# Solr Search: Searching in multiple fields with "AND" Search

Tags: solr

I'm a product owner for the search engine of an e-commerce company and I'm currently "discovering" Solr - since I've never worked with this engine before. Sorry in advance if I don't use the proper terminology.

I have the following typical use case: a user looks for "Apple iPhone". Data set contains fields like Brand = Apple, Product Name = iPhone, Product Type = Smartphone, Category = Smartphones, etc.

In our current setup and according to our external consultants, the engine delivers all results that contain either apple OR iPhone 8. In order to get all the Apple iPhones as results first, they recommend we create a new indexed property containing brand, product name, product type and category all in one and replace the individual properties (so Brand, Product Name, etc.) by this new one. According to them, Solr isn't able to provide an AND search ("look for all products that have apple AND iPhone in their data set").

Is this correct and would you handle this use case the same way?

I'm quite skeptical that Solr isn't able to look for Apple iPhone in separated properties and then deliver results that contain both terms in either indexed properties. The change they recommend also means we lose granularity since multiple fields are being concatenated in one. That also means we won't be able to boost each property separately anymore since they get replaced by the new one.

I'm aware my request might come accross as a "newbie" question but as a non-developper I still haven't been able to figure it out, and the consultants really seem to think that's the only way to handle this use case.

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any reason to lose the granularity; usually you'll want to copy the fields (using the `copyField` instruction) into one or more fields to support different kinds of queries (this also allows you to score hits in the different fields with separate weights). That way you keep all your original fields, and you have a new, separate field that have all the content as a single search field.

Depending on your query use case, you might not need more than the `edismax` query handler and `qf=Brand ProductName ProductType` to query those fields, and set `q.op=AND` (or `mm=<factor>`) to get the behavior you want. If you're unable to match across fields using `qf`, use a field which have the different fields copied into it as the base match (i.e. add `SearchField` as the last field in `qf` as shown above), then boost hits in brand/name/etc. accordingly so exact matches for just "apple" gets scored higher.

Exactly what's considered a match will depend on the tokenization and filtering happening for the field.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Will look into this!